# Textbox control from gridview column is returned but gives empty value

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-interface, gridview

I have succeeded in retrieving Textbox from textbox column of Gridview, but it can't retain the value I have put there. It simply returns reference to textbox but miss the encapsulated value; Following is sample code I'm using to retrieve the textbox and its value; Please help me out of handling such problem.

```
protected void Submit_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {

        int RowIndex = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        string userId = ApprovalParentGridView.DataKeys[RowIndex]["UserID"].ToString();
        GridViewRow row = ApprovalParentGridView.Rows[RowIndex];


        TextBox remarks = (TextBox)row.Cells[6].FindControl("txtRemark");
        string remarks = remarks.Text.Trim();

        ...
    }
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had this in the past and found it to be because the Gridview is loaded in Page_Load and the textbox had its value set in that routine, and Submit_RowCommand is fired afterwards.

You need to rebuild the gridview so that the control is in the controls collection but you need to be careful that you do not put the value in the textbox at the same time or else the code behind will overwrite the value that you user has entered from their browser.

Comment: Glad we could help. Good luck with the rest of your project.